# JRedisGraphCompileTimeException while using time out in the Redish Graph query

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am trying to query Redish Graph with Time out parameter as long but it throws below exception

```
com.redislabs.redisgraph.exceptions.JRedisGraphCompileTimeException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'graph.QUERY' command
```

The method that works now is

```
public ResultSet query(String query) {
   //return graph.query(graphName, query);
   return graph.query(graphName, query);
}
```

But when we try to use below it throws exception

```
public ResultSet query(String query) {
   //return graph.query(graphName, query);
   return graph.query(graphName, query,60000L);
}
```

The Redish  Graph version that we are using is 2.5.1 .

Answer (score 1):

> The Redish Graph version that we are using is 2.5.1 .

There are no [RedisGraph](https://github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph) `2.5.x` [versions](https://github.com/RedisGraph/RedisGraph/tags).

So I am assuming you are meaning [JRedisGraph](https://github.com/RedisGraph/JRedisGraph) version [2.5.1](https://github.com/RedisGraph/JRedisGraph/releases/tag/v2.5.1).

The two methods that you have stated executes same `GRAPH.QUERY` command with same query. The only difference between them is that the later one bears an optional argument `TIMEOUT`. Again, I am meaning the `TIMEOUT` argument while executing `GRAPH.QUERY` command; not while *loading* RedisGraph module into Redis.

It seems you are using a RedisGraph version which does not support the optional `TIMEOUT` argument in `GRAPH.QUERY` command. You can try an updated RedisGraph version.

Comment: so when we set time out while loading module like `loadmodule /usr/lib64/redis/modules/redisgraph.so TIMEOUT 10000` then also it does not work .I tried setting time out to 1 MS but then also no time out